# How can I get the text from a texbox that is dynamically made?

Tags: c#, user-interface, dynamic

```
//Assessment type combobox
comboBoxAssessments.Add(new ComboBox());
System.Drawing.Point pCombo = new System.Drawing.Point(450, 25 + i * 75);
(comboBoxAssessments[i] as ComboBox).Location = pCombo;
(comboBoxAssessments[i] as ComboBox).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
(comboBoxAssessments[i] as ComboBox).Items.AddRange(new object[]{
     "Coursework",
     "Exam"
});
```

I'm working on a grade prediction tool for a university degree that has to have dynamically built controls. The code above dynamically builds a combobox to let the user choose from "Coursework" or "Exam" assessment types. 
"comboBoxAssessments" is an arrayList that holds any given number of comboBoxes.
Once I have the user's selection, I'm saving it into an XML file using the XMLTextWriter class. 
How can I go about getting the user's selection from the combobox during runtime and then write it to an XML file? I've tried using:

```
textWriter.WriteStartElement("Assessment Type", "");                        //Assessment type start
textWriter.WriteString((comboBoxAssessments[i] as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString);
textWriter.WriteEndElement();                                               //Assessment type end
```

but found no glory. If anyone has some ideas, please throw them my way and I'll try them out.

Comment: And why is that your present code is not ok? errors? unexpected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `comboBoxAssessments.Text`. Use this for your second line:

```
textWriter.WriterString(comboBoxAssessments[i].Text);
```

The `Text` property is already a string, and will be the value of the user's selection.

Comment: this will allow the user to just type in things that are not even there to be chosen...

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ this can be prevented by setting the `DropDownStyle` to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`

Comment: I'm very grateful for the reply but I literally just tried that before your response and it worked. but you're right, yes. thank you!

Comment: I strangely had a lot of trouble getting my answer formatted correctly.  Sorry for all the edits.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 yeah sure... +1

Comment: I actually got around the issue of users typing anything that they like by using an if statement to check if the comboBoxAssessments.Text was equal to one of the comboBoxAssessments.items